# Subtraction of different sizes numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have asked a previous question, but I think my example was not clear. I am still trying to subtract two different sizes of numpy arrays from a list of numpy arrays. For example:

```
####Data####
### For same size numpy arrays the subtraction works fine!!!!###
easy_data= [[1,2,3],[2,2,2]],[[1,2,3],[1,2,5]]
d = [np.array(i) for i in easy_data] # List of numpy arrays
res = d[1] - d[0] 
>> array([[ 0,  0,  0],
          [-1,  0,  3]])

##### Current Issue ####
data = [[1,2,3],[2,2,2]],[[1,2,3],[1,2,5],[1,1,1]]
d = [np.array(i) for i in data]
res = d[1] - d[0] #### As the sizes are different I can't subtract them ###
```

**Desired Output**

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  3],[1,1,1])
```

I am kind of slow getting how to work with numpy arrays but I can't figure out how to make this work? Can anybody help me?

Comment: In the desired output, how is the last row computed? is it the last row of `d[1]` minus the last row of `d[0]`?

Comment: I guess that OP would like a kind of implicit expansion of the vector `d[0]` where `d[0][2] = [0, 0 ,0]`

Comment: Yes, @obchardon is correct. I would like d[0][2] = [0,0,0] then I don't need to delete data!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easiest to operate on a slice. If you do not want to erase the original array, use a copy:

```
>>> res=d[1].copy()
>>> res[:d[0].shape[0]]-=d[0]
>>> res
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  3],
       [ 1,  1,  1]])
```